# How to track random free() invalid pointer AFTER program exit?

Tags: c++, c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I've already ran the following command and killed all the leaks and errors reported to it, but I am still getting some random `free(): invalid pointer` AFTER the program finished executing.

```
valgrind -v --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes --show-reachable=yes ./blah
```

Here is the output after I fixed "everything":

```
--31313-- Discarding syms at 0x883f1f0-0x8847648 in /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so due to munmap()
--31313-- Discarding syms at 0x8a4c000-0x8a4f328 in /lib64/libnss_dns-2.12.so due to munmap()
--31313-- Discarding syms at 0x8c54930-0x8c63938 in /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so due to munmap()
==31313==
==31313== HEAP SUMMARY:
==31313==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31313==   total heap usage: 9,190 allocs, 9,190 frees, 1,286,890 bytes allocated
==31313==
==31313== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==31313==
==31313== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 8 from 6)
--31313--
--31313-- used_suppression:      6 U1004-ARM-_dl_relocate_object
--31313-- used_suppression:      2 glibc-2.5.x-on-SUSE-10.2-(PPC)-2a
==31313==
==31313== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 8 from 6)
```

What else can I try to track this random + AFTER my program executed, mysterious invalid free?

EDIT:

The last 2 lines before it exit...

```
    applog("GODDAMN IT");
    return final_rc;
}
```

Here is the "notification" that I get for the `free: invalid pointer`:

```
GODDAMN IT
*** glibc detected *** ./scvpc: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f7975fbd6d0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x373e876166)[0x7f7974134166]
/home/svn/trunk/packages/wvstreams/libwvbase.so.5.2.0(_ZN12WvFastString6unlinkEv+0x1e)[0x7f7975d725be]
/home/svn/trunk/packages/wvstreams/libwvbase.so.5.2.0(_ZN8WvStreamD1Ev+0x491)[0x7f7975d81481]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__cxa_finalize+0x9d)[0x7f79740f41bd]
/home/svn/trunk/packages/wvstreams/libwvbase.so.5.2.0(+0x31e56)[0x7f7975d69e56]
======= Memory map: ========
7f796c000000-7f796c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f796c021000-7f7970000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f7972180000-7f7972196000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 406206                     /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
7f7972196000-7f7972396000 ---p 00016000 fd:00 406206                     /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
7f7972396000-7f7972397000 r--p 00016000 fd:00 406206                     /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
7f7972397000-7f7972398000 rw-p 00017000 fd:00 406206                     /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
7f7972398000-7f797239a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f797239a000-7f797239f000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 390955                     /lib64/libnss_dns-2.12.so
7f797239f000-7f797259e000 ---p 00005000 fd:00 390955                     /lib64/libnss_dns-2.12.so
7f797259e000-7f797259f000 r--p 00004000 fd:00 390955                     /lib64/libnss_dns-2.12.so
7f797259f000-7f79725a0000 rw-p 00005000 fd:00 390955                     /lib64/libnss_dns-2.12.so
7f79725a0000-7f79725ac000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 390957                     /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
7f79725ac000-7f79727ac000 ---p 0000c000 fd:00 390957                     /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
7f79727ac000-7f79727ad000 r--p 0000c000 fd:00 390957                     /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
7f79727ad000-7f79727ae000 rw-p 0000d000 fd:00 390957                     /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
7f79727ae000-7f79727af000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f79727af000-7f79731af000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f79731af000-7f7973220000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 392042                     /lib64/libfreebl3.so
7f7973220000-7f797341f000 ---p 00071000 fd:00 392042                     /lib64/libfreebl3.so
7f797341f000-7f7973421000 r--p 00070000 fd:00 392042                     /lib64/libfreebl3.so
7f7973421000-7f7973422000 rw-p 00072000 fd:00 392042                     /lib64/libfreebl3.so
7f7973422000-7f7973426000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f7973426000-7f797343d000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 392038                     /lib64/libaudit.so.1.0.0
7f797343d000-7f797363c000 ---p 00017000 fd:00 392038                     /lib64/libaudit.so.1.0.0
7f797363c000-7f797363d000 r--p 00016000 fd:00 392038                     /lib64/libaudit.so.1.0.0
7f797363d000-7f7973642000 rw-p 00017000 fd:00 392038                     /lib64/libaudit.so.1.0.0
7f7973642000-7f7973644000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 392041                     /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
7f7973644000-7f7973844000 ---p 00002000 fd:00 392041                     /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
7f7973844000-7f7973845000 r--p 00002000 fd:00 392041                     /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
7f7973845000-7f7973846000 rw-p 00003000 fd:00 392041                     /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
7f7973846000-7f797384d000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 392043                     /lib64/libcrypt-2.12.so
7f797384d000-7f7973a4d000 ---p 00007000 fd:00 392043                     /lib64/libcrypt-2.12.so
7f7973a4d000-7f7973a4e000 r--p 00007000 fd:00 392043                     /lib64/libcrypt-2.12.so
7f7973a4e000-7f7973a4f000 rw-p 00008000 fd:00 392043                     /lib64/libcrypt-2.12.so
7f7973a4f000-7f7973a7d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f7973a7d000-7f7973a89000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 392044                     /lib64/libpam.so.0.82.2
7f7973a89000-7f7973c89000 ---p 0000c000 fd:00 392044                     /lib64/libpam.so.0.82.2
7f7973c89000-7f7973c8a000 r--p 0000c000 fd:00 392044                     /lib64/libpam.so.0.82.2
7f7973c8a000-7f7973c8b000 rw-p 0000d000 fd:00 392044                     /lib64/libpam.so.0.82.2
7f7973c8b000-7f7973ca2000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 392046                     /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
7f7973ca2000-7f7973ea2000 ---p 00017000 fd:00 392046                     /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
7f7973ea2000-7f7973ea3000 r--p 00017000 fd:00 392046                     /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
7f7973ea3000-7f7973ea4000 rw-p 00018000 fd:00 392046                     /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
7f7973ea4000-7f7973ea8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f7973ea8000-7f7973ebd000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 392051                     /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
7f7973ebd000-7f79740bc000 ---p 00015000 fd:00 392051                     /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
7f79740bc000-7f79740bd000 r--p 00014000 fd:00 392051                     /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
7f79740bd000-7f79740be000 rw-p 00015000 fd:00 392051                     /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
7f79740be000-7f7974249000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 391773                     /lib64/libc-2.12.so
7f7974249000-7f7974448000 ---p 0018b000 fd:00 391773                     /lib64/libc-2.12.so
7f7974448000-7f797444c000 r--p 0018a000 fd:00 391773                     /lib64/libc-2.12.so
7f797444c000-7f797444d000 rw-p 0018e000 fd:00 391773                     /lib64/libc-2.12.so
7f797444d000-7f7974452000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f7974452000-7f7974468000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 392058                     /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
7f7974468000-7f7974667000 ---p 00016000 fd:00 392058                     /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
7f7974667000-7f7974668000 rw-p 00015000 fd:00 392058                     /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
7f7974668000-7f79746eb000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 392052                     /lib64/libm-2.12.so
7f79746eb000-7f79748ea000 ---p 00083000 fd:00 392052                     /lib64/libm-2.12.so
7f79748ea000-7f79748eb000 r--p 00082000 fd:00 392052                     /lib64/libm-2.12.so
7f79748eb000-7f79748ec000 rw-p 00083000 fd:00 392052                     /lib64/libm-2.12.so
7f79748ec000-7f79749d4000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 922734                     /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
7f79749d4000-7f7974bd4000 ---p 000e8000 fd:00 922734                     /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
7f7974bd4000-7f7974bdb000 r--p 000e8000 fd:00 922734                     /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
7f7974bdb000-7f7974bdd000 rw-p 000ef000 fd:00 922734                     /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
7f7974bdd000-7f7974bf2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f7975084000-7f79750f3000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 8662332                    /home/svn/trunk/packages/openssl/libssl.so.1.0.1
7f79750f3000-7f79752f2000 ---p 0006f000 fd:00 8662332                    /home/svn/trunk/packages/openssl/libssl.so.1.0.1
7f79752f2000-7f79752fb000 rw-p 0006e000 fd:00 8662332                    /home/svn/trunk/packages/openssl/libssl.so.1.0.1
7f79752fb000-7f79754f2000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 8662328                    /home/svn/trunk/packages/openssl/libcrypto.so.1.0.1
7f79754f2000-7f79756f2000 ---p 001f7000 fd:00 8662328                    /home/svn/trunk/packages/openssl/libcrypto.so.1.0.1
7f79756f2000-7f7975718000 rw-p 001f7000 fd:00 8662328                    /home/svn/trunk/packages/openssl/libcrypto.so.1.0.1
7f7975718000-7f797571b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f797571b000-7f7975742000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 8867973                    /home/svn/trunk/packages/wvstreams/libwvutils.so
7f7975742000-7f7975942000 ---p 00027000 fd:00 8867973                    /home/svn/trunk/packages/wvstreams/libwvutils.so
7f7975942000-7f7975944000 rw-p 00027000 fd:00 8867973                    /home/svn/trunk/packages/wvstreams/libwvutils.so
7f7975944000-7f7975a46000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f7975a46000-7f7975b2d000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 8873068                    /home/svn/trunk/packages/wvstreams/libwvstreams.so
7f7975b2d000-7f7975d2d000 ---p 000e7000 fd:00 8873068                    /home/svn/trunk/packages/wvstreams/libwvstreams.so
7f7975d2d000-7f7975d38000 rw-p 000e7000 fd:00 8873068                    /home/svn/trunk/packages/wvstreams/libwvstreams.so
7f7975d38000-7f7975db7000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 8865320                    /home/svn/trunk/packages/wvstreams/libwvbase.so
7f7975db7000-7f7975fb7000 ---p 0007f000 fd:00 8865320                    /home/svn/trunk/packages/wvstreams/libwvbase.so
7f7975fb7000-7f7975fbe000 rw-p 0007f000 fd:00 8865320                    /home/svn/trunk/packages/wvstreams/libwvbase.so
7f7975fbe000-7f7975fc2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f7975fc2000-7f7975fe2000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 391164                     /lib64/ld-2.12.so
7f79761c6000-7f79761cf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f79761dd000-7f79761e1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f79761e1000-7f79761e2000 r--p 0001f000 fd:00 391164                     /lib64/ld-2.12.so
7f79761e2000-7f79761e3000 rw-p 00020000 fd:00 391164                     /lib64/ld-2.12.so
7f79761e3000-7f79761e4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f79761e4000-7f797623c000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 4301625                    /home/svn/trunk/test
7f797643b000-7f797643f000 r--p 00057000 fd:00 4301625                    /home/svn/trunk/test
7f797643f000-7f7976441000 rw-p 0005b000 fd:00 4301625                    /home/svn/trunk/test
7f7977c9d000-7f7977d25000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7fffabf43000-7fffabf58000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fffabfff000-7fffac000000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Comment: umm..code please?

Comment: Maybe try running valgrind without the suppressions? Also I'm fairly sure it's possible for valgrind to miss some types of memory corruption if it happens in a bizarre enough way. And a corrupted heap would cause an error message from `free`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, can't, is a giant program with several in-house libraries. I'm basically seeking any suggestions from any Valgrind experts to see what else I can turn on in Valgrind to help locate this weird issue.

Comment: Your program cannot produce an invalid free after it has finished running, because *it is not running* at that point.  If such an error occurs at that time, then it is a different program that produces it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I interpreted that as getting an error after `main()` has returned, and before the process exits, i.e. from a destructor or from somewhere within the C runtime. I might be wrong of course.

Comment: @codenamezero, what notification are you actually seeing about the problem?  How are you associating it with the program in question and that program's state at the time the error occurs?

Comment: @codenamezero, also, you have tagged both C and C++.  These are different languages, and the possible nature of the problem depends to some extent on which one is actually in use (or whether both are).  Please specify.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, updated the original post with the "notification". Is basically the typical invalid free core dump error, but even valgrind didn't reported anything from those libraries.

Comment: Th stack trace indicates the problem is coming from `WvFastString::unlink()` in libwvbase.so.5.2.0, so try attaching a debugger there to see what it is doing (likely some global object destructor, where the global object has been corrupted)

Answer (score 2):

Usually that happens, when you accidentally delete an object, that is owned by a static, or global object, that will try to release it after `main()` has finished.

Prefer to use `std::shared_ptr<>` or `std::unique_ptr<>` depending on the ownership for owning pointers, and raw pointers for non owning pointers. Then any explicit `delete` in your code is a code smell. `delete` needs a raw pointer, which can only be a non owning pointer, so another part of the code owns this object and should take care of deleting it.

Comment: That's plausible, provided that the OP has been imprecise when he says that the error occurs "after the program finishes executing".  Execution of cleanups is part of execution of the program.

Comment: Hum... I will try to reduce the number of static stuff in the program then, there are tons of static variables being declared and used in many places. (Not my code, FML)

Comment: @codenamezero You have a clue that it's related to a WvFastString. That might be helpful. If the error is repeatedable, you can try removing code until the error goes away, helping to narrow down what code is causing the problem.